# HTML canvas setTranslate does not work with onClick

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an HTML canvas with some content. This content needs to be draw translated to the canvas. That is working. But now I need to detect which object is clicked, so I need to search in the coordinates of the objects to find an matching one. But since the objects are drawn at a different x, y position then known I don't know how to match them.

I have created this fiddle with the situation. I want to highlight the correct object when clicked. One thing to keep in mind is that this canvas is used in an environment (HMI screen connected with PLC) where I don't have the full functions which are normally available in a browser. That means also that I only get an x and y coordinate on the 'onClick' function.

https://jsfiddle.net/gkho89wd/

This code is not the cleanest but I use this to try some things.
Quick explanation of this code:

I have an array with some objects (boxes)

```
const rawPositions = [];
```

every position has some properties including x and y, width and length. Those are used to draw some rects on the canvas. I also calculate an 'ratioX' and 'ratioY' to scale everything. Those x and y are used to actually draw.

Before I draw the rects, I'm doing an 'setTransform' to horizontally flip the canvas:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ctx.height);
```

How can I translate the coordinates from the click event to the 'original' ones?

Comment: You can invert the matrix used to perform the initial transformation, DOMMatrix has an invert function. From a brief look, you could create a matrix corresponding to the transform needed. You can transform a ctx with it, then you can invert it and use it to transform some point, or the ctx itself, as needed. I'm a little perplexed at the transform code you show though, that's code for performing a vertical translation of ctx.height units. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform You can find DOMMatrix docs there too.

Comment: Canvas elements are a type of image: they have pixels. The pixels have not information about their origin. You may be able to use a library such as [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) to manage image data from a higher level, but I have only encountered it in answering similar questions - this is not a recommendation or opinion to not use it.

Comment: @traktor I tried to use fabric.js, also for some other options they provide but it is not supported in the supposed environment due to the limited DOM unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the **findShape** function to take into account the transformation applied to the canvas. You should flip the y coordinate back and then use that to search for the clicked object.

```js
async function findShape(oX, oY) {
  console.log('findShape', oX, oY)

  // Flip the y coordinate back to match the transformed canvas
  const flippedY = ctx.height - oY;

  const clickedBox = placedCarton.findIndex(b => {
    return (b.ratioX <= oX) && (b.ratioX + b.width >= oX) &&
           (b.ratioY <= flippedY) && (b.ratioY + b.length >= flippedY);
  });

  moveArrows = [];
  positions = [];

  if (clickedBox >= 0) {
    placedCarton.forEach(b => b.active = false);
    placedCarton[clickedBox].active = true;
    activeBox = clickedBox;

    updateCartonCanvas();
    const box = placedCarton[clickedBox];

    await window.savePositions();

    const prePos = window.prePos;
    const postPos = window.postPos;

  } else {
    console.log('no box found');
  }
}
```

This modification takes into account the fact that the canvas is flipped vertically. By flipping the y coordinate back (using **ctx.height - oY**), you can now correctly detect which object is clicked.

Comment: Nice! Very simple and although it was not the full solution it helped me looking in the right direction and now I have a working solution!